# What is the reasoning behind Bragg-Williams approximation?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

According to The book Statistical mechanics by Pathria, The Bragg-William approximation states that "the energy of an individual atom in the given system is determined by the (average) degree of order prevailing in the entire system rather than by the ( fluctuating) configurations of the neighboring atoms" What is the reasoning behind the above statement?